# How to get the folder details for a mail using messageID?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mailcore2

I am using Mailcore2 to fetch mails from IMAP server. If I have a messageID of a mail using that can I get the folder in which it is for Outlook and Yahoo mails?

I am using the following code for fetching messages

```
 self.imapMessagesFetchOp =
     [self.imapSession fetchMessagesByNumberOperationWithFolder:inboxFolder
                                                    requestKind:requestKind
                                                        numbers:[MCOIndexSet indexSetWithRange:fetchRange]];

     [self.imapMessagesFetchOp start:
      ^(NSError *error, NSArray *messages, MCOIndexSet *vanishedMessages)
      {

        }];
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How about using the *to address* of the e-mails?

Comment: If we are using to address will I get which folder that mail is in even if it is in some folder created by the user

Comment: No you won't.  Please show the code you are using to fetch the messages.

Comment: I have added code for fetching messages

Comment: OK, so you specify the folder as part of the call, so how does that differ from the folder you are asking for in your question?

Comment: After fetching if the user changes the folder for the mail in the web app how will I know the new folder?

Comment: There is no modseq value for outlook mail

Comment: OK, so you know the folder the message was retrieved from and your question is how you store that folder along with the message?

Comment: No after fetching the folder is changed from some other client so How will I get the new folder to which it is moved as fetching the labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to get the folder of mail using the messageID. If you want to know in which folder it is you can the search the messageID in all the folders available but it is not efficient. For further details check the following links

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501

https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions